# Highlight all cells in a row that are not blank based on value in one cell within row

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

Trying to highlight only cells within the row that are not blank if "shipper printed" is selected in column "M".

So far my unsuccessful conditional formatting:

```
=AND(NOT(ISBLANK(A:N),$M:$M="SHIPPER PRINTED"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please select ColumnsA:N and try the formula rule:

```
=AND(NOT(ISBLANK(A1)),$M1="SHIPPER PRINTED")
```

CF handles the ranges for itself, based on your selection, but you do need to bring the final parenthesis forward, to 'close' the NOT sooner.